# How do I find the contact ID on a checksum link, after a form is submitted?

Tags: quickform

I'm trying to make an extension that does the following:

1. User clicks link in email
2. Form loads, extracts the contact ID from the querystring (along with a checksum for security), and customises the form appropriately
3. User submits form
4. Changes are saved
5. Form reloads, showing updated data

My problem comes at step 5, as the form no longer knows what the contact ID is. How can I pass the contact ID to this page? It's no longer in the querystring, and I can't find it anywhere...

Sorry if this is basic stuff - I've tried to figure it out from the existing profile code.

Comment: I think we have some code that could help on this by creating a session when a checksum is used. asking colleague about getting it out of a private repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the code [here](https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.checksumpersist) and see if it can help with what you need.

Comment: that told me exactly what I needed to know. Thank you very much for going the extra mile on this! Really appreciate it.

Comment: great. hopefully you can either share back, or submit a patch to ours if it meets some other generic situation that might help others?

Comment: yep definitely - will do